# Comparing BIC values

Tags: r

I have three different BIC values with 3 different cluster values

VEV-BIC value(9512) with 2 clusters
EEE-BIC value(9509,5) with 5 clusters
VEV -BIC value (9509,9) with 3 clusters

Based on the BIC values how do I say which is best, and why?

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not in direct link with some programming issue, it is probably better if you ask over at [stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).